# Group Total after each group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a requirement to display the records in groups (based on 2 columns - Partner & Type) along with group totals after each group and finally a grand total. Attached image has the required output also attached how it is coming up now in SSRS 2008. 
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVRhM.jpg](http://Current%20Report) 
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVRhM.jpg](http://Expected%20Report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Initially create a table with two columns with a group on partner.
   The table has 4 rows: one for headers, two for the partner group and one as footer (like the border layout).
2. Create a table with your column names and drag it on the header cell
3. Create a table with row detail data and drag it on partner group first row
4. create a table with data grouped on type and drag it on partner group second row
5. create a table with data grouped on type(clone the previous) and drag it on the footer total cell

[image]

Your final result should look like the image below

[image]

Running the report:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please elaborate on implementing the same in SSRS?

Comment: My solution is implemented in SSRS. The first image is from the designer (on the left I have added the table nesting logic) and the second image is from the report execution (values are based on your image data, removed extra columns for clarity)

Comment: Am unable to achieve this. Can you please let me know what all components (lists, tables) you have used and where all you have applied groups/totals? Little detailed step by step procedure will help. Thanks!